# What can I do to import csv-file into Python correctly, if I have "#" generally as delimiter but partially as a part of the title?

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv, delimiter

I am to import this [csv file](http://movies.task-sss.krasilnikov.spb.ru/data/9f66a575a6cfaaf7e43177317461d057) into Python dataframe, having delimiter "#{1}", hence it counts 13 columns, but I have this error with several lines:

"ParserError: Expected 13 fields in line 803, saw 14. Error could possibly be due to quotes being ignored when a multi-char delimiter is used."

and the issue is that these troubling lines look like this
"Revolution#9#9118#"9118"#"350000"#15.11.2002###Thriller/Suspense##""##7,3#252"

where "Revolution #9" means "Revolution №9", just title of the film, not delimiter, though the program doesn't understand that and counts one excessive column because of that. Teacher forbid to edit the original csv file to fix it. Only using a code.

Is there some code which can edit this csv file in Python replacing this sign in the film's title with the other? or soome other ways to fix this problem, please?

Here is my code used, just in case

```
import pandas as pd
movies=pd.read_csv('movies.csv', 
                   sep="#{1}",
                   names=["Title", "US Gross", "Worldwide Gross", "Production Budget", "Release Date", "Distributor", "Source", "Major Genre", "Creative Type","Director","Rotten Tomatoes Rating","IMDB Rating","IMDB Votes"],
                   engine='python',
                   skiprows=1)
movies = movies.replace(to_replace='"', value="", regex=True)
movies
```

Comment: Well, `Revolution#9` is not surrounded by quotes, so you have a malformed file.  There is no way for the computer to automatically know what to do.

Answer (score 1):

I think the csv.DictReader module will help you. 
Here an untested example how to use this module

```
from csv import DictReader

with open(file_name, 'r') as csv_file:
    fieldnames = ["Title", "US Gross"] # Add all youre rows here
    csv_lines = csv.DictReader(csv_file, fieldnames=fieldnames, delimiter=',')
    for line in csv_lines:
        # Example how to access the column 'Title'
        title = line['Title']
        # here you can replace the content
```

Comment: Did you mean to make this in the end:                                                                      
movies = movies.replace(to_replace='#', value="N", regex=True) ?

Comment: e.g. to replace " in the title write

Comment: You did not specify in which line of your code snippest your error occurs.
So i assume that the error occured in the line with movies=pd.read_csv.
My implementation is an alternative implementation using csv instead of pandas.
e.g. to replace " in the title write
    title.replace('"', '')
to replace " in all columns
    for key in line:
        line[key] = line[key].replace('"', '')